# What is the best way to secure (2x6) wood framing to the concrete portion of the garage opening?

Tags: doors, concrete, garage

I live in a raised ranch. The lower half of the house is divided into a 2 car garage and a living area. 
Also the lower half of the house has 8 ft. ceiling (about 4 ft. concrete walls and 4 ft. wood walls).
The wood framing (2x6) on each side of the garage doors are warped and separating from the concrete portion of the 
garage walls. When standing in the drive way, a noticable gap exist between the concrete portion of the 
garage opening and the (2x6) wood framing. I want to replace the (2x6) wood framing on each side of the garage opening.

What is the best way to secure (2x6) wood framing to the concrete portion of the garage opening?
Should I use pressure treated wood?

Comment: A picture would go a long way here. Link to it and someone with higher rep will embed it for you.

Comment: @gregmac: New users can now add images directly: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/146318

Comment: Is the "concrete portion" of the wall in question a poured concrete wall, or CMU blocks (A.K.A. cinder blocks)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use pressure treated wood. There would often be anchor bolts cast into the wall to hold the 2x6s, these can be reused. Sometimes powder actuated fasteners are used. Besides needing a special tool to install these, they often do not penetrate well into old, well cured concrete.

You can install new expansion anchors by drilling holes with a hammer drill. Whichever method, back it up by using construction adhesive to limit future warpage.

Comment: Wedge anchors is the strongest. If its a poured wall you can put them anywhere. Cinder block you will need to make sure the cores(holes) is filled with concrete. I dont know how bad the 2x6 is now but a wedge anchor will surely straight out any warping and suck it down with 5,000 lbs of pressure.